# Running Android+Opencv+NDK App on a real device

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I've followed the Face-detection sample method and I successfully programmed an object detection app on emulator.

Now, when I try to run it on real device, the moment I click on detection button, it crashes. Logcat says `"OpenCv/StaticHelp >> First attempt to load libs failed"`. I've installed OpenCVManager on my device and even run some samples like puzzle or even face detection.

My question is: Could it be the OpenCV include on Android.mk that is hard-coded like

```
include /home/xxx/Desktop/OpenCV-2.4.2-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put native camera libraries to libs folder in your project. 
Add also OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on and OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on to your Android.mk file
for more check the tutorial on [opencv4andriod website](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android)